# Bootstrap Vue form radio buttons - how to change radio buttons width

Tags: css, vue.js, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-vue

I use [Bootstrap-vue](https://bootstrap-vue.org/docs/components/form-radio) and I have a group of 2 radio buttons (`b-form-radio-group`) I'm trying to set each radio button to 50% width. I created the following code structure:

```
        <b-row>
          <b-col cols="12" sm="auto" class="text-center">
            <b-form-group class="w-100">
              <b-form-radio-group
                button-variant="outline-primary"
                buttons
                class="d-flex flex-wrap"
              ></b-form-radio-group>
            </b-form-group>
          </b-col>
       </b-row>
```

The classes `d-flex` and `flex-wrap` don't have an effect. And currently, I see the radio buttons like this:
[image]

How can I change each radio button's width to 50%, and in the end to see them like that (if possible without CSS styles):

[image]

Comment: I'm not sure what I did differently but here is a codepen correctly showing the radio buttons as expected by the second picture: https://codepen.io/pen?&editors=101&layout=left ... well I actually added the radio buttons that were not shown in your snippet

Comment: The link is empty

Comment: sorry I forgot I had to subscribe... I'm quite sure it's something that wasn't required before. Anyway here is the correct link https://codepen.io/yaselore/pen/zYymBwM?editors=101&layout=left

Comment: if you wrap <b-col> with a tag <b-row> it doesn't work

Comment: yes I verified that adding back the `<b-col>` will change the layout. Mistery solved. I crafted my demo in the rush and didn't notice

Comment: Can you not add the `w-50` helper class to `<b-form-radio>` to achieve what you want?